# ElasticSearch indexing with nested collections in document

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I have been wrestling with an issue trying to index a document into a brand new index in ElasticSearch. My document looks something like this:

```
    {
  "id": "",
  "name": "Process to run batch of steps",
  "defaultErrorStep": {
    "id": "d44fdeae-80ff-4509-8504-9dfbd7284631",
    "name": "General Error Handler",
    "type": "ERROR",
    "reference": "error",
    "onError": "DEFAULT"
  },
  "startingStep": "one",
  "steps": [
    {
      "id": "d44fdeae-80ff-4509-8504-9dfbd7284631",
      "name": "Step One",
      "type": "CHAIN",
      "reference": "one",
      "onComplete": "two",
      "onError": "DEFAULT",
      "parameterKeys": {
        "param-a": "value-a",
        "param-b": "value-b",
        "param-c": "value-c"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "d44fdeae-80ff-4509-8504-9dfbd7284631",
      "name": "Step Two",
      "type": "CHAIN",
      "reference": "two",
      "onComplete": "two",
      "onError": "DEFAULT",
      "parameterKeys": {
        "param-a": "value-a",
        "param-b": "value-b",
        "param-c": "value-c"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "d44fdeae-80ff-4509-8504-9dfbd7284631",
      "name": "Step Three",
      "type": "BOOLEAN",
      "reference": "three",
      "onTrue": "four",
      "onFalse": "five",
      "onError": "DEFAULT",
      "parameterKeys": {
        "param-a": "value-a",
        "param-b": "value-b",
        "param-c": "value-c"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "d44fdeae-80ff-4509-8504-9dfbd7284631",
      "name": "Step Four",
      "type": "LOOP",
      "startingStep": "seven",
      "steps": [
        {
          "id": "d44fdeae-80ff-4509-8504-9dfbd7284631",
          "name": "Step Two",
          "type": "CHAIN",
          "reference": "six",
          "onComplete": "seven",
          "onError": "DEFAULT",
          "parameterKeys": {
            "param-a": "value-a",
            "param-b": "value-b",
            "param-c": "value-c"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "d44fdeae-80ff-4509-8504-9dfbd7284631",
          "name": "Step Five",
          "type": "FINISH_VOID",
          "end": false,
          "reference": "seven",
          "onError": "DEFAULT",
          "parameterKeys": {
            "param-a": "value-a",
            "param-b": "value-b",
            "param-c": "value-c"
          }
        }
      ],
      "reference": "four",
      "onComplete": "five",
      "onError": "DEFAULT",
      "parameterKeys": {
        "param-a": "value-a",
        "param-b": "value-b",
        "param-c": "value-c"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "d44fdeae-80ff-4509-8504-9dfbd7284631",
      "name": "Step Five",
      "type": "FINISH",
      "end": true,
      "reference": "five",
      "onError": "DEFAULT",
      "parameterKeys": {
        "param-a": "value-a",
        "param-b": "value-b",
        "param-c": "value-c"
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration": {
    "settings": {
      "property-a": "a",
      "property-b": "b",
      "property-c": "c",
      "property-d": "d",
      "property-z": "z123"
    }
  }
}
```

My issue is that due to the nested structure of the property "steps" and its ability to also have loop objects with "steps" inside of that, I get into an issue of field duplication when trying to index. I understand the reason (I think) as to why my document is failing but I need to index it all the same. When I try to index the document I get the following error:

```
ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=json_parse_exception, reason=Duplicate field 'type'\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@84a0697; line: 1, column: 186]]]
```

Again, I understand why this is an issue but I figured I could address this with mappings in my index. I have tried `nested` object type, `flattened` object types and even setting `index:false` on the steps field just to see if I could get the document to go in. But, no chance. I know this is a going to be a simple fix somewhere I just cannot see but does anyone have any thoughts on what I can try to get this document to index.

I am using ElasticSearch 7.3.1 via the latest Java SDK release. I have bypassed the java code for now and just using POSTMAN to send the indexing command but still I get the same issue.

Below is an example of one of the mappings I have tried.

```
{
  "_source" : {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "properties" : {
    "name": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "raw":{"type": "keyword"}
      }
    },
    "steps":{
        "type":"nested",
        "properties":{
            "steps":{
                "type":"flattened",
                "index":false
            }
        }
    },
    "configuration.settings":{"type":"flattened"}
  }
}
```

As well as a more explicit mapping to cover the "defaultErrorStep" object.

```
{
  "_source" : {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "properties" : {
    "name": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "raw":{"type": "keyword"}
      }
    },
    "defaultErrorStep":{
        "type":"object",
        "properties":{
            "id":{"type":"text"},
            "name":{"type":"text"},
            "type":{"type":"text"},
            "reference":{"type":"text"},
            "onError":{"type":"text"}
        }
    },
    "steps":{
        "type":"nested",
        "properties":{
            "id":{"type": "text"},
            "name":{
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "raw":{"type": "keyword"}
                  }
            },
            "type":{"type": "text"},
            "reference":{"type": "text"},
            "onComplete":{"type": "text"},
            "onError":{"type": "text"},
            "parameterKeys":{"type": "object"},
            "onTrue":{"type": "text"},
            "onFalse":{"type": "text"},
            "startingStep":{"type": "text"},
            "steps":{
                "type":"nested",
                "properties":{
                    "id":{"type": "text"},
                    "name":{
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "raw":{"type": "keyword"}
                          }
                    },
                    "type":{"type": "text"},
                    "reference":{"type": "text"},
                    "onComplete":{"type": "text"},
                    "onError":{"type": "text"},
                    "parameterKeys":{"type": "object"},
                    "onTrue":{"type": "text"},
                    "onFalse":{"type": "text"},
                    "startingStep":{"type": "text"},
                    "steps":{
                        "type": "flattened",
                        "index":false
                    },
                    "end":{"type": "boolean"}
                }
            },
            "end":{"type": "boolean"}
        }
    },
    "configuration.settings":{"type":"flattened"}
  }
}
```

Please also bear in mind that the nature of the document is to outline a process/workflow of logic and the structure is key and I would also say valid JSON. So in theory the steps property could nest 3,4,10 levels if it had to. So Ideally I wouldn't want to be updating the mapping every time a new level was added in the data.

Any help anyone can give me to get this document to index would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

**EDIT:**

I have since removed my explicit mapping from my index and let dynamic mapping take over as all my objects fit into the base types dynamic mapping supports. This has been successful and I am able to index the document shown above with infinitely nested steps no problem. I then tried the same operation with the same document structure using the JAVA SDK and this failed with the same duplicate field exception. This indicates to me the issue is with the JAVA SDK and not something native to elasticsearch itself.

Dynamic mapping is the better option in my case as I have no control over how many levels steps could eventually get to.

Has anyone experienced any issues with the SDK behaving differently to the base product?

Comment: Is it possible to create an example with less fields? That makes it easier to give an answer. I'm not sure if what you're trying to do is possible in elasticsearch.  In the 4th step of the root document you create a new step with the same structure as the root document. This implies you can nest those 'sub'-steps even further (inifinitely). Maybe it is better to reference to an id in the steps.

Comment: @jvwilge that's what I thought too. Maybe separating the steps, from the flow, but with the possibilty of sub steps being able to nest infinitely, I feel I will still get into the same issue. I would have a reference object that matches the parent exactly. Thoughts?

Comment: In the `steps` field I would reference by id : `"steps": [
      "d44fdeae-80ff-4509-8504-9dfbd7284631",
      "d44fdeae-80ff-4509-8504-9dfbd7284632",
   "d44fdeae-80ff-4509-8504-9dfbd7284633"
  ]`

It makes searching a bit more difficult however. Do you really need elasticsearch? This structure looks more like a fit for a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

I am running elastic 7.3.1 and with following index mapping i am successfully able to create index with nested types inside nested type.

```
PUT new_index_1
{
    "mappings": {
        "_source": {
            "enabled": true
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "raw": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "steps": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "steps": {
                        "type": "flattened",
                        "index": false
                    }
                }
            },
            "configuration.settings": {
                "type": "flattened"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Following index creation also works for me

```
PUT new_index_2
{
    "mappings": {
        "_source": {
            "enabled": true
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "raw": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "steps": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "steps": {
                        "type": "nested"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Document Indexed**

```
POST new_index_1/_doc
{
  "name": "ajay",
  "steps": [
      {
        "test": "working",
        "steps": [
            {
              "name": "crow"
            }
          ]
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I notice the document you posted didn't have the type field in it. Do you think that property could be the issue? Should I separate out the steps to a linear list and then have a separate property for the flow of the steps?

Comment: which es version are you using. Yeah it can be a issue if you have same field in a different type in the same index. It will throw duplication error then.